# How to add multiple users for access?

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and HTML, but have been dabbling a bit.  I have a successful login code, and a working logout button.

I am trying to add multiple username and passwords though, and the current way I have it, only the last line for a set username and password is actually working (Nullifying the first one).

Below is the code I am using, the two lines that I am having an issue with are

```
$validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "password";
$validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin2" && $_POST["password"] == "password";
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
$errorMsg = "";
$validUser = $_SESSION["login"] === true;
if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
  $validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "password";
  $validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin2" && $_POST["password"] == "password";
  if(!$validUser) $errorMsg = "Invalid username or password.";
  else $_SESSION["login"] = true;
}
if($validUser) {
   header("Location: /logs"); die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="input" action="" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" value="<?= $_POST["username"] ?>" id="username" name="username" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" value="" id="password" name="password" />
    <div class="error"><?= $errorMsg ?></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sub" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean login 2 users in a single form submission? Why would you do that?

Comment: Are you trying to check if either one of admin or admin2 is trying to login? 
If so, `$validUser = ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "password") || ($_POST["username"] == "admin2" && $_POST["password"] == "password") ;` should work.

Comment: That worked, thank you!